# Finding the exterior of a set $S$

Tags: real-analysis

Let
$$S = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \bigg( 1- \frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}, 1- \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} \bigg] = (0,1/2] \cup (3/4,7/8] \cup (15/16, 31/32] \cup \cdots$$
I know that an exterior point is a point where $x_0$ is in the interior of $S^c$ and therefore the exterior is the set of these points but I'm struggling with finding $S^c$.

This is what I have so far: 
$$S^c = (-\infty, 0], (1/2, 3/4], (7/8,15/16], (31/32,\infty) $$
I think that I'm wrong here, maybe I'm overthinking it but can anyone let me know if I've done something wrong?

After I've found $S^c$, I know that I just need to find the interior of it which is just making all of the closed part of the sets open in order to make all the points interior points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S^c=(-\infty,0]\cup(1/2,3/4]\cup(7/8,15/16]\cup\cdots\cup \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n-1}},1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n}}\right]\cup\cdots\cup[1,\infty)$

The interval $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n-1}},1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n}}\right]$ get's smaller and smaller (whose length is half of the preceding interval) but will never get past 1. Finding the interior of $S^c$ should be easy.

Comment: if it never reaches 1 then why is [1,∞) closed on the left side as if it reaches 1? The interior of  S^c should be fine because it's just the same but all of the closed brackets become open as every point must be an interior point

Comment: $[1,\infty)$ is included in $S^c$ because it is not in $S$ (for the same reason that $S$ never get past 1. Except for $(-\infty,0]$ and $[1,\infty)$, the rest are its complement in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: ahh thank you, one more question: is the set of limit points for this set S just equal to S? because surely every deleted epsilon neighbourhood of x0 in this set contains a point of S for every single x0 in the set

Comment: There is one more point not in $S$ which is a limit point of $S$, the number $x=1$, since the interval approaches that value.

Comment: so the set of limit points  = S U {1}?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that boundaries of $S$ are also limit points of $S$. So you need to include the endpoints of each interval.

Comment: so this would mean that the set of limit points = S but every open bracket is closed U {1}? way more than I first thought lol